# What is the next shape?

Tags: pattern, visual

which one is the correct answer of the following picture? What is the algorithm of shapes sequence?

[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> The answer is A.
>
> Count the number of straight lines on each shape, and it corresponds to the digits of pi.  The shapes you provided match 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5.  The following digit of pi is 3, so the answer is A.