# The Security to the Party [Part 8]

Tags: password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing ~ his famous recipe for Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people the host knows and trusts, whom he gave the password to enter to.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "6", and the guest replies "0".

The second guest arrives. The security says "5", the guest replies "1".

The next guest arrives.  The security says "10", the guest replies "1".

The next guest arrives. The security says "7", the guest replies "2".

The next guest arrives.  The security says "8", the guest replies "2".

You walk up to security and get "3", what is the correct response?

> Hint:  Look at some of the previous solutions in this series.

Comment: TWO PART 7's??? FIGHT! FIGHT! FIGHT!

Comment: Atleast this time, there is no friend to get the humiliation

Comment: Where's the links to the other parts? You're not going to give credit for the ideas?

Comment: @warspyking, there is a "party-security" tag now lol, so all the links have gone.

Comment: Well link to the party-security tag.

Comment: @warspyking farewell party-security tag, looks like it has been changed to "password" now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct answer is...

> 2 - for each response, you should count the number of enclosed areas in the lowercase letters for the challenge word.
>
>  six = no closures
>  five = 1 closure (e)
>  ten = 1 closure (e)
>  seven = 2 closures (e, e)
>  eight = 2 closures (e, g)
>
>  three = 2 closures (e, e)

Answer (score 7):

> 2. The number of closed spaces in the lower case spelling of the number the guard gives you.

Comment: Ill get this sooner or later. Every theory i try fails on just one number

Comment: This sounds correct.

Comment: I tried counting the loops of the letters aswell but is falls short on number "8" if spelled with capital letters so im guessing that's wrong aswell

Comment: Well that's a nice quick edit from the wrong answer to the right one ;-)

Comment: well i was saying in my previous comment that i was thinking exactly what you were saying. and you can see that the previous comment hasnt been edited and was written Before you posted your answer. you posted it as an answer Before me though so congratulations.

Comment: @Legotruck,  You were so very very close with your first attempt so well done.